# Looking for a Harry Potter/Katekyo Hitman Reborn crossover, where Shamal finds Harry coming back to life

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, crossovers, katekyo-hitman-reborn

I am looking for a crossover fan fiction (may be a series of one shots) where Shamal infiltrates some Famiglia's compound and finds Harry almost dead. He takes Harry out of there and then they are ambushed and Harry helps Shamal take them down.

Harry uses Apparition to seem very fast, and fights with a knife.

I think Harry comes to be known as QuickSilver (I keep remembering that word).

Harry saves someone during the Ring Battles, and the Varia get it on video. (Somebody comments that it is not just fast, it is instantaneous)

There was also another chapter, (maybe in Harry's POV) which is just after Shamal finds Harry. They go to Venice by plane and meet a Triad assassin on the flight. And the three are shot at in Venice. (And Harry goes crazy about gelato).

Anyone know what this is?

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/Harry-Potter-and-Katekyo-Hitman-Reborn-Crossovers/224/2734/ - One of these, presumably

Comment: These might help you; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum it wasn't on fanfiction.net which is where I read it.

Comment: But that crossover list did show me somebody who had borrowed the plot and mentioned the author's name, and I found the fic on ao3. Apparently, the author took it down from ffn. Thanks for the help! It's Raison d'Etre by cywscross. Should I answer the question on my own or delete it? Sorry about the double comment.

Comment: Self-answer if you've found it. Don't forget to mention *how* you found it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The story is [*Raison d'Etre*](https://archiveofourown.org/works/13252986) by cywscross.

I had read this story on fanfiction.net, and so all my searches were for that website only. I started going through each fanfiction in the the HP Katekyo Hitman Reborn crossover list on ffn with Harry Potter as a character, and I found one fic where the author had written a Harry X Shamal story, and mentioned that she got the plot from Raison d'Etre by cywscross.

I looked for the mentioned fic and found it on ArchiveofOurOwn (remember - I had only been searching fanfiction.net). A look at the author's page on ffn showed me that they removed all their stories from ffn recently, which is why I couldn't find it. All their stories are now on Ao3 (and tumblr).

Anyway, as I mentioned in the question, Harry comes to be known as QuickSilver in the mafia

> "I know what you're doing," He finally said gruffly. "That damn innocent act isn't going to work. Everyone in underground Italy and several other countries have heard of Quicksilver."
>
> Harry blinked blankly at the swordsman, absently tucking his knife away. "'Quicksilver'?"
>
> Squalo scoffed. "That's you, isn't it? Black hair, green eyes, British, Trident Shamal's new partner. Quicksilver."
>
> Harry pinched the bridge of his nose. "'Quicksilver'? That's what people are calling me? Seriously?"

Also, Harry fights with a silver knife, and is very fast, hence the name.

> Squalo snorted. "You have a silver knife, trash, and you're rumoured to be fast.

Harry saves Lussuria and Ryohei after their ring battle, ans Squalo gets it on tape. When reviewing, he notes that Harry was not just fast, he was instantaneous.

> But Squalo hadn't even seen him move. The rumours all said Quicksilver was fast. This was leagues beyond fast. This was instantaneous.

There was a prequel to this, called "Give It A Year", but it has not been uploaded on ao3 yet.

Thanks a lot Valorum, for giving me that crossover directory link! It wasn't until then that I started reading every story.